# Why having guru is must to advance spiritually?

Tags: guru

For me guru is just another human with his understanding, learning and experinces. So I dont get trust on someone worthy to take him as my guru as he is also just another human like me.

Almost every spiritual organisations ask to have guru which I dont understand that why do I need guru and ristrict myself to him only?

Why having guru is must to advance spiritually?

Answer (score 3):

The following is an excerpt from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> Mr. Evans-Wentz continued another day: “May one have more than one
>   spiritual master?”
>
> M.: Who is a Master? He is the Self after all. ***According to the
>   stages of the development of the mind the Self manifests as the Master
>   externally.*** The famous ancient saint Avadhuta said that ***he had
>   more than 24 Masters***. The Master is one from whom one learns
>   anything.
>
> The Guru may be sometimes inanimate also, as in the case of Avadhuta.
>   God, Guru and the Self are identical.
>
> A spiritual-minded man thinks that God is all-pervading and takes God
>   for his Guru. ***Later, God brings him in contact with a personal
>   Guru*** and the man recognises him as all in all. Lastly the same man
>   is made by the grace of the Master to feel that his Self is the
>   Reality and nothing else. Thus he finds that the ***Self is the
>   Master***.

---

One of the accepted practices of resorting to the God, for bringing into contact of his/her personal Guru, is to doing pArAyana (reciting text), with sincerity and intent of becoming  a worthy disciple, of his/her choice.

- Some may recite regularly sundara kAnda
- some may recite durga saptasathi
- someone else may choose bhAgavatam
- a few more select guru charitra - pertaining to Sri Dattatreya.

Answer (score 1):

> गुरुर्ब्रह्मा गुरुर्विष्णुर्गुरुर्देवो महेश्वरः ।
>   गुरुरेव परं ब्रह्म
>   तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नमः ॥१॥

A Guru is absolutely necessary for every aspirant in the spiritual path. It is only the Guru who will find out your defects. The nature of egoism is such that you will not be able to find out your own defects. Just as a man cannot see his back, so also he cannot see his own errors. He must live under a Guru for the eradication of his evil qualities and defects.

For a beginner in the spiritual path, a Guru is necessary. To light a candle, you need a burning candled Even so, an illumined soul alone can enlighten another soul.

Some do meditation for some years independently. Later on, they actually feel the necessity for a Guru. They come across some obstacles in the way. They do not know how to obviate these impediments or stumbling blocks. Then they begin to search for a Master.

Only the man who has already been to Badrinath will be able to tell you the road leading to it. In the case of the spiritual path, it is still more difficult to find your way. The mind will mislead you very often. The Guru will be able to remove pitfalls and obstacles, and lead you along the right path. He will tell you: “This road leads you to Moksha; this one leads to bondage.” Without this guidance, you might want to go to Badrinath, but find yourself in Delhi!

Read more at [this](http://sivanandaonline.org/newsupdates/the-role-of-the-guru/) source about importance of Guru

Comment: Guru is important BUT in today's time it's almost impossible to find such Guru who can guide us. So in kali yuga almost eveyone is on its own Or in the hands of God. Just follow teaching of Bhagwat Geeta/shastras and walk on spiritual path by chanting name of your beloved God. Don't depend on anyone by thing "I will meet some Guru one day and then I will start my spiritual progress". Start it now without delay, without worrying whether you have Guru or not.

Comment: Guru is not impossible to find if u try hard. Following any scriptures is useless unless u find ur Guru. That is the essence of Hinduism. @Rishabh

Comment: @rickross How can we try to find in our busy schedule. All day job and in night with family. Even if we got, how we will knwo if he is fake or real. Why we even need Guru if we can do devotion. Even Krishna in bhagwat Geeta taught us all possible ways of getting moksha, so we already got Guru as Krishna. Krishna never said in BG to get Guru first before trying to get moksha. But instead he told us way of moksha and said walk on it.

Comment: That is childish way of thinking. Everyone needs a Guru even Krishna Rama had Gurus. If u had read Gita then it says u need to be under the guidance of a Guru. If I can not find time for spirituality then whom should I blame? Its my own Karmas. So finding a Guru is impossible is a lame excuse. If we try hard and we have less bad Karmas from previous births then we can surely get one in this life. @Rishabh

Comment: Going by ur logic the Guru Shishya paramapara must have stopped from the time Gita was spoken. But was that the case? Reading books of some Gurus and having a personal Guru, who gives mantra in ur ear, are two different things.@Rishabh

Comment: In vaishnava sect, we take brahmasabandha, that is the lifetime bond with a guru assigned, the Guru, is worshipped at every particular festival and however one is busy Guru is always there to solve the moral conflict one is facing.

Comment: There is also the problem of identifying a guru worthy of following among a surfeit of market savvy purveyors of spiritual goods. As with all things in life a default outlook of skepticism will serve one well.   The primacy and preeminence accorded by Hinduism to the institution of the Guru unfortunately has the side effect of exploitation of the gullible @rishabh